# Method returns multiple object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC 4 project which consumes services from a web api 1 project .

Here i need to have a service method where i pass an id and a string named **action** based on the action
        the service should go and fetch data from the table. Here i will have different cases based on the actions.

**So if my action is person it should go to person table and based on the id passed it should return LIST**

**IF action is email it should fetch data from the Email table based on the id passed and should return LIST**

Is it possible to achieve from single method as my return type will be different in each cases? If so what will be my return type of the method?

```
public Email GetEmail(int id)
{
    Email email = db.Emails.Find(id);
    if (email == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }

    return email;
}


public List<Email> GetEmailByPerson(int personid)
{
    List<Email> email = db.Emails.Where(n => n.PersonID == personid).ToList();

    if (email == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }

    return email;
}

public Person GetPerson(int id)
{
    Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
    return person;
}
```

My get service call always call the same method
Modified as below  based on the comments

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "DefaultApi",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "ActionApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                    );
```

Code for controller action is:

```
[ActionName=EmailsByPersonID]
public IEnumerable<Email> GetEmailsByPersonID(int personid)
{
    var emails = db.Emails.Where(n => n.Personid == personid).ToList();

    if (emails == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }

    return emails.AsEnumerable();
}
```

I have made these changes in the web api.config file and decorated my method with action name : EmailByPerson and the service call is http://localhost:XXXX/ActionApi/Email/EmailsByPersonID/1

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why you don't build this as two web api calls.  The total implementation work is less because each call is simpler.

Comment: One size fits all = Fits everyone badly. Write 2 methods.

Comment: I am not able to call two get /post method within same controller. I am using web api1. If i have make multiple method with same parameter int : ID it always calls one get method. I read about attribute mapping. But i am not able to achieve this in WebAPI 1

Comment: an interesting point here is, you can control the routing of your api, and you can actually determine what action to invoke thus. Can I take a look at your route template?

Comment: It is the default template  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: @Amit: Do you mean to define two route template . I wonder if you can show me an example

Comment: you can override `SelectAction` method from `ApiControllerActionSelector` class, and control the action selection criteri(s).

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection .. read more here

Comment: @Amit, i have edited my question by defining multiple route . but i am getting 404 not found.i feel i am missing some configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this template -

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public string GetName(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }

    public string GetNameById(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute
        ("default","api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

then make the calls to api like -

```
http://localhost:port/api/My/GetName/12
http://localhost:port/api/My/GetNameById/12
```

works for me atleast. :)

**UPDATE**

You could also do it like this -

```
public class CustomActionInvoker : ApiControllerActionSelector
{
    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");

        var routeData = (string)controllerContext.RouteData.Values["optional"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(routeData))
        {
            var actionInfo = controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).ToList();
            var methodInfo = actionInfo.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(routeData)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                return new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor(controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor, methodInfo);
            }
        }
        return base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
    }
}
```

In the config -

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{optional}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new CustomActionInvoker());
```

And change the api call to -

```
http://localhost:port/api/My/Email/12
```

May be the previous example follows exactly this approach out of the box.

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{EmailsByPersonID}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

Comment: No. Just keep this default route.

Comment: I am confused.Now i have 2 route configuration in webapi.config file. can you please elaborate

Comment: see my edit(s). you should pass in call to api , the actual action name from your controller.

Comment: Thanks Amit.I tired the first approach. It worked. But i have to change all my other service call also to include the action name and to specify Get and Set. Is it possible to have a default one without action name and another route configuration for the methodss where i have several get/post method with same signature..

Comment: Can you just brief what is the second approach following

Comment: so we can nly have one route config for all service calls

Comment: No, but the first one is ootb,while the second tries to do it according to the dev

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this approach, but you don't ask us to make opinions about it but a specific question. And the answer to the question is YES it's possible.

You can use HttpResponseMessage for this purpose:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetXx(string type, int id)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case "xx":
            Type1 obj1 = <your logic>;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj1);
        case "yy":
             ....
}
```

Comment: In other words, add a second parameter to indicate the type of return type. This will avoid you multiple actions

Comment: I just explain your approach. You added `string type` so that you do not need another action methods, but you only write a single action method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to fix this.

```
  1. You can use [RoutePrefix("api/Service")] for your controller and [Route("User")] and [Route("Email")] ,
```

you should be able too call your web api
api/service/user (GET,POST,PUT,Delete) , 
same thing goes with your Email as well

```
 2. you can create IModel/IResult/SuperClass for your User/Email, and your web api method would be like IEnumerable<IModel> Get(string entityType) or 
 IModel Get(string entityType,int id)
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I tried the first method earlier , but there i am not finding [Route] attribute. I am using web api1 . I think it is feature added in web api 2